# Getting Compiler errors while using asList() method

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am attempting to use the Arrays.asList method to store sentences that I have read from a txt file. However I am getting compiling errors telling me about incompatible types and how there are no instances. I'm assuming I left something out accidentally or one of my lines are off so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Prompt user to enter file for reading
      System.out.print("Please enter the name of a file: ");
      String fileName = kb.nextLine();
      // Stores user's input file to open
      File file = new File(fileName);
      // Reads user's file
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

      while(inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         String str = inputFile.nextLine();
         ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

This is the error I am getting

error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List conforms to ArrayList

Comment: @Carcigenicate it sure does accept an array (maybe part of reason why it is in `Arrays`)

Comment: `Arrays.asList` doesn't return an `ArrayList`.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` does **not** return an `java.util.ArrayList` which you probably importing, try `List<String> list = Arrays...`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I doubt that too... compiler isn't that bad at inferring types

Comment: @JohannesKuhn actually it does return an `ArrayList`, just not the `java.util` one - it is  an inner class of `Arrays` also (badly) called `ArrayList` (that is, `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`)

Comment: If you look at the signature, it says that it returns a `java.util.List<T>`. The compiler doesn't care if the method would at runtime return a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` or `java.util.ArrayList` or `null`. The only important information the compiler uses is it's declared return type. And that is `java.util.List<T>`.

Comment: And relying on the fact that it returns a specific but not specified type will make your code brittle, and will break when `Arrays.asList` returns something like `jdk.internal.misc.ArrayBackedList`. This will probably never happen, but if it does and your code breaks, then it's your fault.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));`

You want to grab the list not the ArrayList

Edit: Grab not return

Comment: @Andreas I mean the `Arrays.asList()` is not returning an ArrayList not that line